# CUDA cudaMalloc failed after running kernel with huge static arrays

Tags: c++, c, cuda, static-array

I have a kernel which uses about 2GB local memory. My `cudaMalloc` which tries to alloc 2.5GB memory fails if I run that `kernel_func` before.

I found out that 2GB memory is still occupied after finished running `kernel_func`, which leaves only 1.5GB for my `cudaMalloc`. Does anyone has a solution or explanation?

I know that using global memory for `kernel_func` can solve the problem but for some reason I need to use local memory for that huge local static array.

```
__global__ kernel_func() {

    // The huge static array goes here
    short my_array[50000];

}

int main() {

    kernel_func<<<64, 128>>>();
    // my_array is still occupying memory are this point

    // This cudaMalloc will fail with insufficient memory
    cudaMalloc(/* 2.5GB data */);
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the kernel is actually running? And what is the runtime error message returned by the cudaMalloc call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow `kernel_func` to finish (e.g. with `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`), then I doubt that `my_array` is still "occupying memory" as you suggest, after the kernel completes, i.e. at the point of this comment:

```
    // my_array is still occupying memory are this point
```

You could be more certain with a call to [cudaMemGetInfo()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gd5d6772f4b2f3355078ecd6059e6aa74) at that point.

Nevertheless, it's likely what you're experiencing is memory fragmentation of some sort.

The only way I know of to "clean the slate" would be a call to [`cudaDeviceReset()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1gdcc2c6f914eb9461565b12648faa5e28) at that point.  However that will kill any operations as well as any allocations on the GPU, so you should only do it when you have no other activity going on with the GPU, and you must re-allocate any GPU data that you need after the call to `cudaDeviceReset()`.

Certainly if you can arrange your allocations using `cudaMalloc` instead, that might be easier.

Note that `cudaDeviceReset()` by itself is insufficient to restore a GPU to proper functional behavior.  In order to accomplish that, the "owning" process must also terminate.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329377/reset-cuda-context-after-exception/56330491#56330491).